# Is there any way to change the SMBIOSVersion value in win32_bios in windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, windows-10, bios

As illustrated in the picture bellow, by tweaking the registry in windows 10 I was able to change the bios version but not the SMBIOSVersion, which is what i want. Is there any way to alter it? Not necessarily permanently. I don't care if the value is restored after a reboot, i just want the win32_bios containing an SMBIOSVersion that i have specified until shutdown so calls to it will return my specified version.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's coming from WMI, and the Win32_BIOS provider is defined in `c:\Windows\System32\wbem\cimwin32.mof` as a dynamic provider calling from cimwin32.dll.

But it does seem to be possible to override it; create a new file somewhere, e.g. `c:\user\spkone\test.mof` and put this in it:

```
#pragma namespace ("\\\\.\\root\\CIMv2")

class Win32_BIOS
{
    [key]
    string SMBIOSBIOSVersion;
};

[DYNPROPS]
instance of Win32_BIOS
{
    SMBIOSBIOSVersion = "wow";
};
```

Run an administrator command prompt or PowerShell, and run `mofcomp test.mof`.

[image: Image of running mofcomp.exe to compile the test .mof file]

Before:

[image: Image of get-wmiobject win32_bios before the change]

After:

[image: Image of get-wmiobject win32_bios after the change]

I got this far and then stopped, I don't know how far the change reaches, or what the implications are. It does show in another PowerShell process, anyway. I'll leave it to you to fill in the other details ;)

Answer (score -2):

Quoting from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> **SMBIOSBIOSVersion**
>
> Data type: **string**
>   ***Access type: Read-only***
>   Qualifiers: MappingStrings ("SMBIOS|Type 0|BIOS Version")
>
> BIOS version as reported by SMBIOS.
>
> This value comes from the **BIOS Version** member of the **BIOS Information** structure in the SMBIOS information.

Basically, this value reports information obtained from the BIOS. To modify the value you'd need to modify the BIOS, i.e. flash the chip with a new firmware.